# Implementing an onValueChange for a UISwitch in OBJ-C but not when the user touches/changes the value

Tags: objective-c, user-interface, listener, uiswitch

Is there way to implement an onValueChange listener in Xcode/Objective C for an UISwitch but not an onTouch listener? So I want a method to be called when the value of the UISwitch changes without user input. (This will happen programatically via a text SMS service)

Comment: How is the SMS setting the value of the switch? This may be an easier point to observe the change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The listener is only called when the `UISwitch` gets toggled by the user touching it. If you programmatically set it, the listener won't be called. But since you're programmatically changing it, just call your listener yourself at the time you change it.

Comment: I found a better way of going about it; it was a SMS twilio app controlling an electrical circuit through iPhone; I just had  second toggle to determine if the user wanted to or not to listen to a specific output pin.